# Creating Custom Customer ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I am hoping to create unique customer ID's by using the first three letters of last name, first letter of first name, and date person became a client.

Example:

```
FIRST LAST  DATE 
John  Smith 12/29/2013

Customer ID : SMIJ_12292013
```

How do i setup a field that i will name `ID`, to read information from these different columns and combine them into one column in order to make the `customer ID`?

I am using Desktop Access 2013.

Comment: pLEASE SEE below answer & Please tell me is that correct or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select Concat ( Left(Last,3), Left(First,1),'_',Date);
```

use this query as insert statement

Answer (score 0):

Wont a trigger do the job ? Create one for the Insert operation for the table and in it put the code that creates it and inserts it in the id column ... this way you will be able to use simple Insert statements rather than passing parameters to a stored procedure or running complicated queries.

Answer (score 0):

I would use php in order to process the fields and then insert the customer id later in the script reading the information from the table

Answer (score 0):

You will do like this.
If you want to read from three different field.

```
 SUBSTRING(col1, 1, 1) + SUBSTRING(col2, 1, 1) + SUBSTRING(col3, 1, 1)
```

You can concatenate these three string into single column.